# Show $\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_j} = m_i \dot r_i^T\frac{\dot r_i }{\partial \dot q_j} $

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation

This is a basic result in lagrangian mecanics. Let $T$ be the kinetic energy, $r_i$ be the position of the $i^{th}$ particle in the system I need to show $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot q_j} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial m_i \dot r_i^T \dot r_i}{\partial \dot q_j} = m_i \dot r_i^T\frac{\partial\dot r_i }{\partial \dot q_j}. $$

I am stuck on taking the derivative of the $\dot r_i^T \dot r_i$ quantity. By chain rule,  $$\partial(\dot r_i^T \dot r_i) = \partial\dot r_i^T\dot r_i + \dot r_i^T\partial\dot r_i.$$
How can the right hand side transform into $$\dot r_i^T \frac{\partial\dot r_i }{\partial \dot q_j}~?$$

Comment: Think about what $r$ and $r^T$ are and observe that $(\partial r^T) r = r^T \partial r$. Also, you are missing some $\partial$ sings in your equations, as it seems.

Comment: Those damn $\partial$ things...I will think about it thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\partial\dot{r}_i^T\dot{r}_i}{\partial\dot{q}_j}=\dfrac{\partial\dot{r}_i^T\dot{r}_i}{\partial\dot{r}_i}\dfrac{\partial\dot{r}_i}{\partial\dot{q}_j}=2\dot{r}_i^T\dfrac{\partial\dot{r}_i}{\partial\dot{q}_j}$$
(A simple chain rule, while bearing in mind that $\dot{r}_i^T\dot{r}_i$ is essentially $\dot{r}_i^2$. You just need a transposed vector on the left to keep the dot product.)